# Airflow: set a default value in code when Variable doesn't exist without an exception

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a little problem, I want to do the typical conditional like

```
setting_x  = Variable.get('setting_x')
variable = setting_x if setting_x else 0
```

But since the Airflow model throws an exception when the key doesn't exist is impossible to do it without *trycatching* and that's not very cool.

Is there any solution that I'm missing to solve that case? I've searched in the whole internet of course, but without a solution yet.

Thanks,
Angel

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can set the default for the Variable if it doesn't exist when you're retrieving it with the `get` method.

`variable  = Variable.get('setting_x', default_var=0)`

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/variable.py#L127

Comment: Hey! thank you! it works so I will mark it as solved, but I'm having more or less the same problem since the value should be always != None. Let's say another example:

Comment: slack_channel = Variable.get('SLACK_CHANNEL', default_var=None)

slack_channel = slack_channel if slack_channel else os.environ['SLACK_CHANNEL']

Comment: In that case, it still throwing an exception, that's a little constraint since we can't manage a possible None value without _trycatching_, don't you think so? Python is not my main language so probably I'm missing something but is strange to me can't manage a possible None value in a model

Comment: `slack_channel = slack_channel if slack_channel else os.environ['SLACK_CHANNEL']` should work unless your `SLACK_CHANNEL` environment variable is also None. If you can never have it be None and there is a possibility that the env SLACK_CHANNEL is also None, I would add a check at the end to ensure it is something else -- `if not slack_channel: slack_channel = 'DOES NOT EXIST'`

Comment: Any way to do this with a Jinja template? `{{ var.value.setting_x or 0 }}` will error out if the variable setting_x doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version of the previous answer (keyword `default_var` omitted):

```
variable  = Variable.get('setting_x', 0)
```